# Volume form on sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, volume, spheres

How can I show the $n$ form: $$i_{\bf X}\ dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{n+1}=\sum (-1)^{i-1} x^i \, dx^1 \wedge\cdots \wedge \widehat{dx^i} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{n+1}$$ is nowhere vanishing on the sphere $S^n$? 
The vector field $X$ is given by $$X=\sum_ix^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$$

I'm thinking whether it's correct to say that since for every point on $S^n$ there is at least one $x^i$ is not 0, then by linear independent, the n form must be non-zero everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure those are linearly independent as forms on the sphere? (Note that each $n$-form, without the coefficient, vanishes at certain points when restricted to the sphere.)  Better, think about the geometry, as $X$ is the unit normal. What is the value of the original $(n+1)$-
form evaluated on $X,v_1,\dots,v_{n}$ if the $v_i$ are a basis for the tangent space at a point?

Comment: You didn’t answer my question. What I asked you to do *is* the value of the  given $n$-form on $v_1,\dots, v_n$. But my apologies. I had a typo,  now corrected.

Comment: I have no idea how can a n form act on a vector field, as far as I know, only when n=1, the operation makes sense. Am I still misunderstanding you?

Comment: We're plugging $n+1$ vectors into the $(n+1)$-form $dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{n+1}$.

Comment: So you mean $(dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{n+1})_p(X_p,(v_1)_p,\dots, (v_n)_p)$, then it will be the determinant of… oh, wait, I get your idea :)